# How to remove a symbol from a column in R?

Tags: r

I have a CSV file in which one of the columns, which is supposed to be a number, has a symbol "|" appended to the end of the number by mistake. I want to remove it.

The data set looks like this:

```
gender  age  probability|
 M       51    0.4567|
 F       38    0.6789|
```

As you can see, the `probability` column is appended with a `|`

How do you remove the `|` of the entire column in R?

Comment: `sub('\\|$', '', df$prob)`

Comment: `df$prob <- sub('\\|$', '', df$prob)` and fix the name with `names(df)[3] <- 'probability'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the unwanted symbol is in the last column, you can use `comment.char` to get rid of it upon reading the data from file. This way, no further manipulation and coercion on columns is necessary. Here it is with `read.csv()`.

```
read.csv("x.csv", comment.char = "|")
#   gender age probability
# 1      M  51      0.4567
# 2      F  38      0.6789
```

If the column in question is not the last in the file, try `fread()` with a system command.  This will remove all `|` no matter where they are in the file.

```
data.table::fread("cat x.csv | tr -d '|'") ## system dependent 
#    gender age probability
# 1:      M  51      0.4567
# 2:      F  38      0.6789
```

Where the file `"x.csv"` is created with

```
writeLines("gender,age,probability|
M,51,0.4567|
F,38,0.6789|", "x.csv")
```

Note that I made it into a csv because you state you have a csv file.